# ThingsBoard use case with virtual devices

Tags: iot, thingsboard

I have devices. And the devices are sending raw sensor values to a data collection service. The data collection service persists all sensor events grouped by sensor id and set id.

Now I want to use ThingsBoard to visualize the data.

Is it possible to create virtual devices in ThingsBoard? Each virtual device should represent a sensor and get the data from the existing persistent storage. And I dont want to get all sensor values for all devices. But I want to select a device and a set and then visualize only these values. The data should not be stored in the embedded Cassandra database. Is it possible to load the selected data only in memory? Everytime I select any data, ThingsBoard should pull the selected data again. Or an extra servcie should push the data again.

Comment: I was also wondering if I could do this following this link https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/action-nodes/#rpc-call-request-node

Answer (score 0):

Devices can be virtual or physical. You need a method to post data to TB. If it's a software its OK, TB don't care about that. 
When you create devices, you can create dashboards that can interact with devices data. You select what devices you want to use.

Unfortunately you need to save the data in the database. You cant show anything in dashboard if is not stored.